# Merging SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, merge

We are using SQL Server and historically have had 3 different databases per tenant. Plan is to only have one. I.e. we have to merge 3 into 1.

What is the best way of doing this? Pick largest of 3 and simply recreate tables from other 2 and pump data in?

Comment: Sitting down and program? Depending on how independent the tenants are we talk of a small or a quite large project. Way too little information - and way too broad scope - for a Q&A site.

Comment: this is nothing to do with tenants, really just looking for best way to combine 3 databases into one without too much code. We can move views, stored procedures by just running sql script, but I am trying to avoid or automate move of actual data. One of databases quite large ( usually several gigabytes. ).